# RxJava Sliding Window

Tags: java, kotlin, rx-java, observable, reactivex

I have an observable which emits data and I want to initially buffer it for three seconds and then there must be a sliding of one second after initial buffer. This is more like `buffer(timespan,unit,skip)` where the skip is on the timespan.

Sample:

```
ObservableData,TimeStamp : (5,1),(10,1.5),(30,2.8),(40,3.2),(60,3.8),(90,4.2)

ExpectedList : {5,10,30},{10,30,40,60},{30,40,60,90}
```

I can achieve this by creating a custom operator. I just want to know is there any way to do it without relying on the custom operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it can be solved with builtin operators. Code below demonstrates one of the approaches, though things can get tricky when used for hot or non-lightweight cold sources - I encourage you to use it for educational/ get-an-idea purposes, and not production use

```
 @Test
fun slidingWindow() {
    val events = Flowable.just(
            Data(5, 1.0),
            Data(10, 1.5),
            Data(30, 2.8),
            Data(40, 3.2),
            Data(60, 3.8),
            Data(90, 4.2))
            .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
    val windows = window(windowSize = 3, slideSize = 1, data = events).toList().blockingGet()
    Assert.assertNotNull(windows)
    Assert.assertFalse(windows.isEmpty())
}

fun window(windowSize: Int, slideSize: Int, data: Flowable<Data>): Flowable<List<Int>> = window(
        from = 0,
        to = windowSize,
        slideSize = slideSize,
        data = data)

fun window(from: Int, to: Int, slideSize: Int, data: Flowable<Data>): Flowable<List<Int>> {
    val window = data.takeWhile { it.time <= to }.skipWhile { it.time < from }.map { it.data }
    val tail = data.skipWhile { it.time <= from + slideSize }
    val nonEmptyWindow = window.toList().filter { !it.isEmpty() }
    val nextWindow = nonEmptyWindow.flatMapPublisher {
        window(from + slideSize, to + slideSize, slideSize, tail).observeOn(Schedulers.io())
    }
    return nonEmptyWindow.toFlowable().concatWith(nextWindow)
}

data class Data(val data: Int, val time: Double)
```

The test above yields
 `[[5, 10, 30],
  [10, 30, 40, 60],
  [30, 40, 60, 90], 
  [40, 60, 90], 
  [90]]`

Comment: Thanks it helps in arriving at the solution desired in my case

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by operators `timestamp()` and `scan()`, buffer elements inside scan and ispect them. 
Example for the idea (it does not buffer initial 3 seconds), with `compose()` operator.

```
/**
 * Sliding overlapping window. If exactCount of elements are within timespan
 * then groups elements into List otherwise filtered out
 */
fun <T> slidingWindow(
    timespan: Long,
    timespanUnit: TimeUnit,
    exactCount: Int
): (Observable<T>) -> Observable<List<T>> {
    return { from ->
        from.timestamp(timespanUnit)
            .scan(
                ArrayDeque<Timed<T>>(exactCount + 1),
                { queue: ArrayDeque<Timed<T>>, t: Timed<T>
                    ->
                    queue.addLast(t)
                    if (queue.size > exactCount) queue.removeFirst()
                    queue.removeAll { timed -> queue.last().time() - timed.time() > timespan }
                    queue
                }
            )
            .filter { it.size == exactCount }
            .map { it.toTypedArray() }
            .map { it.map { timed -> timed.value() } }
    }
}

    @Test
    fun slidingWindow() {
        val testSequence = "asXZYe".asIterable()
        val timespan = 5000L


        Observable.fromIterable(testSequence)
            .compose(slidingWindow(timespan, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, 3))
            .test()
            .assertValues(
                arrayListOf('a', 's', 'X'),
                arrayListOf('s', 'X', 'Z'),
                arrayListOf('X', 'Z', 'Y'),
                arrayListOf('Z', 'Y', 'e')
            )
    }
```

My github: [github.com/OndrejMalek/RxSlidingWindow](https://github.com/OndrejMalek/RxSlidingWindow)